# Service Cloud Console

Tags: visualforce, service-cloud-console

This one has me stumped -

CTI needs to pop user to a new case record.  To do this, I am routing CTI to a VF page, and the VF page has a simple url redirect in it. The merge var c is the id of a new case created in the controller;

```
<apex:page controller="pw_anonymousCallCC">
<body>
<script> location.href='/ui/support/servicedesk/ServiceDeskPage#%2F{!c}'; </script>
</body>
</apex:page>
```

The page redirect happens as you'd expect, and a primary tab is generated, but then all I get is a 'Data Not Available' error on the tab itself.  I know the case record is being created successfully - any ideas anywhere out there would be most appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

issue was the url needed a '/' preceeding each of the merged id's. Solved.

Answer (score 1):

Are you screen popping a new console every time? This isn't the best approach. It would be like opening a new instance of Outlook for every email.

If not, and you're staying in the Console and just want to open a tab to the new case, use screenPop API in Open CTI.

If you are using the desktop adapter, screen pop to the VF page and use openPrimaryTab from it.

Also, can you inspect the frame of your new tab and paste the url here?